# how to override function in display suite extras

Tags: display-suite

I'm looking for a way to override a few things in Display Suite Extra's ds_search_extra_variables function. Easy enough to update the module directly, but I'd prefer to override it in template.php or as part of a custom module if possible, just haven't had any luck with getting the site to recognize overrides (ex. THEMENAME_ds_search_extra_variables in template.php or MODULENAME_ds_search_extra_variables in a custom module).

Here's what I'm hoping to accomplish:

1. make some minor adjustments to the language in "Your search for XYZ gave back..."
2. avoid the 'Your search for "" returned...'
3. clean up character encoding issues like 'Your search for ""%40the" gave back..."

I did try overriding a couple of other functions (those that call ds_search_extra_variables), but I pretty quickly ended up with a large chunk of hte extras module in my custom module and still wasn't seeing any progress.

Any advice regarding how to get this working would be much appreciated.

Thanks!